# Display posts by most "liked" within the past 7 days

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been using this tutorial to generate a post like system on my site (basically word for word): https://hofmannsven.com/2013/laboratory/wordpress-post-like-system/

At the very bottom of this page, it explains how to display the most liked posts in the past day. I adjusted the code to account for most likes in the past week. However, after 7 days, the post disappears even if a new like was registered..it will not show back up on the feed.

For example, say a post starts doing well (posted 21 days ago) and begins to get a lot of likes, it should show up at the top of the feed.

Here's what I have right now and it just shows the most liked posts of all time:

```
$week = date('W'); //changed from year with 'j' input
$year = date('Y');
$args = array(
  //'year' => $year,
  //'week' => $week,
  'post_type' => array( 'post' ),
  'meta_key' => '_post_like_count',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'paged' => $offset,
  'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
  'post__not_in' => array($current_post_id) //skip current displayed post
);
```

I think it has to do with being able to correlate a date with the a specific like?

Here's the process I was thinking:

- get all posts
- for all posts, get likes, filter the likes to be within 7 days, if yes add the post ID and post likes count in an array
- Sort the array by likes count
- Display the resultant array

I think that's the process, I just dont know how to accomplish this :(

Again, the site I mentioned has all the code that is in my `functions.php` so just have a look at that!

Here's the current live site: https://www.uncvrd.co